# Radio button onchange function not working if radio is checked directly by link parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A Radio Button runs a `onchange` jQuery function when we click on it. But if we directly check this same radio button by a link parameter, the function is not called. Please, how to solve this? I've tried changing `onchange` to `onclick` without success.

Page I'm working on: Once any Store is manually selected, the onchange function will hide the Store DIV and show the Category DIV, simulating a step filter. http://www.hotsales.com.br/procurar/

This is the direct link parameter to automatically select some Store. But this way, the onchange function doesn't run, so the Store DIV is still visible and the Category DIV still hidden. http://www.hotsales.com.br/procurar/?offer_store=852

This is the first function that should run when Store is selected (both manually or by direct link).

```
/* AJAX SEARCH*/
$(document).on( 'change', '.advanced-search input', function(){

start_ajax_search3();

    $.ajax({
        url: $('.advanced-search').attr('action'),
        data: $('.advanced-search').serialize(),
        success: function( response ){
            handle_ajax_search_response( response ); /*this function hide/show desired DIV*/
        },
        complete: function(){
            end_ajax_search();
        }
    });
});
```

This is how the DIVs are hidden/showed:

```
function handle_ajax_search_response( response ){
    var $response = $('<div>'+response+'</div>');
    $('.ajax-results').html( $response.find('.ajax-results').html() );
    $('.ajax-sidebar').html( $response.find('.ajax-sidebar').html() );
    $('.category-filter').show();
    $('.store-filter').hide();
    $('.offer-type-filter').show();}
```

Comment: What checks the checkbox by link parameter? The backend?

Comment: just get it to call `.click()` on the relevant radio button as the page loads

Comment: @Panomosh but the condition to be checked isn't page load but parameter in the url.  The idea is good but you have to condtionally call that script depending on that parameter you speak of.
If that parameter and the check is obsereved by the server so should be the included script that runs the click callbaclk on load.

Comment: Thank you all! The Alessandro's suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call your function on `change` and on document `ready`, ex:

```js
function test(chk){
  console.log("called by" + $(chk).attr("id"));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  if($("#chkTest2").is(":checked")){
    test($("#chkTest2"));
  }
});

$(".chkboxes").on( 'change', function(){
  test(this);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="chkboxes" type="checkbox" id="chkTest1">Test 1
<input class="chkboxes" type="checkbox" id="chkTest2" checked="checked"> Test 2
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: This is my adapted code: `$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('input[id^=offer_store_]').is(":checked")){
    $('.store-filter').hide();
    $('.category-filter').show();
    $('.offer-type-filter').show();
  }
});` GOD bless you!

Comment: I used `'input[id^=offer_store_]'` as a wildcard ID selector. So, it will work for every store ID which begins with `offer_store_` like offer_store_1507, offer_store_852, etc. Perfect!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Bye.